# Wrong data is written to binary file

Tags: fwrite

I would like to save an array with values less than a 1000 to a binary file using this approach:

```
int * arrayF = new int[300];
// fill the array
const char *filePath = "data.bin";
FILE *file = NULL;
if ((file = fopen(filePath, "w")) == NULL){return 1;}
fwrite(arrayF, 4, 300, file);
fclose(file);
```

However, after reading the .bin file, several of the values are incorrect. I can not figure out where is the problem. Could anyone, please, point out on what I am doing wrong?

Here's what the *printf()* function outputs as the content of the *arrayF* and the same is expected in the file:

```
for (int i=0; i<300; i++){
    printf("%d\n",arrayF[i]);
}
```

28
27
25
26
27
31
27
29
27
27
23
21
21
18
18
21
23
25
23
24
25
24
22
21
20
20
21
21
21
19
18
17
15
15
14
14
15
13
12
***10
10
10***
10
9
8
7
6
6
6
6
5
5
4
4
4
4
4
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
3
4
5
6
6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
9
9
8
9
10
11
11
11
11
11
11
8
5
5
4
3
3
2
3
5
6
4
4
5
8
5
5
3
2
3
6
11
16
20
21
23
27
27
29
28
30
37
49
31
50
50
64
229
381
339
191
363
243
232
104
80
115
94
98
51
73
131
202
266
387
400
443
399
319
355
293
166
76
67
86
48
44
60
43
45
45
36
34
39
36
30
31
27
30
23
20
22
26
20
5
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
1
2
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
6
19
23
21
16
22
33
33
34
28
36
36
34
28
62
26
22
23
19
52
73
33
67
31
42
26
23
42
42
44
42
26
26
13
4
3
5
2
3
7
6
8
11
11
9
24
29
35
45
35
69
55
108
79
75
115
242
362
429
345
206
75
83
63
84
22
77
67
102
23
14
38
18
20
25
22
6
11
13
7
3
3
2
5

When I view the file content [online](http://hex-works.com/eng), I see there is some discrepancy with what is expected. For example, beginning at the 40th integer, I get some weird byte shifts, so I end up having an extra byte:

[image: *enter image description here*]

Comment: Open with "wb".

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That helped, thank you! I will go ahead and folllow RaymondChen's suggestion as a duplicate.

Comment: FYI, the reason is that windows is converting the `\n` to `\r\n`, unless you specify "binary".